# Concatenate characters to an empty string

Tags: c

I have an empty string (char *str) and I want to concatenate characters to this string. I have tried this
    char *str;
    char arr[10]; //where as arr contains some characters

And when I do this:

```
str=str + arr[0];
```

It does nothing to `str`.

Comment: what language? C? you might want to format your code by using 4 spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C you cannot concatenate two strings using `+`, as strings are not inbuilt datatype, use `strcat()` which is defined in `string.h`.

A small example:

```
/* strcat example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    char *str;  
    char arr[10];
    puts("Enter some string:");
    scanf("%9s",arr);
    str=malloc(256);
    strcat (str,arr);
    strcat (str," World.");
    puts (str);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

> Hello

**Output**

> Hello World.

Answer (score 3):

Use strcat to concatenate strings.  strcat_s is similar but is safer since it has length validation.